# How to handle links to formerly legitimate software that now includes malware

Tags: discussion

A couple of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565218/how-to-know-what-process-is-using-a-given-file) recommend a piece of software which is potentially distributing malware according to a [comment on one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3565229/776176).

From looking into the software a bit more it appears that once upon a time it was ok, but now appears to be distributing a toolbar which is potentially associated with malware according to the [comments on the download page](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/comments/).

Whether this software in particular includes malware or not, it raises the question of what the correct course of action is in this type of situation - comment, flag, edit out the link, or leave it alone and let the buyer beware as it were?

**Edit**
For the specific question I referenced this has now become a moot point as it has been locked and I can neither comment on nor edit the answer now.

Comment: If they're link only answers, they don't belong.

Comment: SO answers should not be providing links to executable tools.

Comment: One is effectively link only, the other is a perfectly good answer which includes the link as an alternative tactic at the end.

Comment: @MartinJames That's a bit too broad. Tools that are used for development are on-topic. This is... maybe borderline, but not blatantly off-topic.

Comment: @Laurel all your crap are belong to us?

Comment: Why was this locked!?

Comment: @MartinJames: Questions asking for links to tools are not allowed.  Answers that choose to recommend a tool ARE allowed, because it's the expert's choice whether to recommend a language feature, built-in function, external tool, etc... and when recommending an external tool providing a link is natural.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*If you're confident* that the link does more harm than good, don't hesitate to remove it *right now*.

You can start a discussion on meta or in a chatroom to hear other opinions about the software if you feel you need them. If it turns out that you were wrong, the edit can easily be reverted again and no damage will be done. On the other hand, if you are right and the software causes harm on its users, every hour the link stays there is a potential damage. Sure, we're all supposed to be skilled computer users and be smarter than blindly downloading and installing any crap somebody links to but my confidence that this assumption holds true is actually pretty low.

If you feel that the link is not merely an addition to the answer but essential for it to be valid, consider re-phrasing the text. For example, replace

> You can [download this fantastic tool](http://www.example.com/evil-malware) and get the job done quickly.

with something like this.

> There used to be a tool called *Evil Malware* that allowed you to get the job done quickly. However, usage of *Evil Malware* is no longer recommended and the link to its download page has been removed from this answer as several people have raised concerns that it has severe security flaws and might contain evil malware.

It doesn't invalidate the answer and those who feel inclined enough can still look at the edit history or search the web for the tool at their own risk. Also note that I have phrased the text in a way that avoids associating the original author of the answer with the claim that the software is evil or makes exaggerated claims. There is no need to be more dramatic than what the facts currently provide for.

If the answer becomes totally useless after removing the link to an external page, then it doesn't meet the quality standards of the site anyway and should be flagged for deletion. Still edit the offending link out as deletion might take a while.

While it is generally good etiquette to discuss edits to other people's posts, I don't believe that we need to tolerate links to malware on the site any longer than necessary. This might also be a legal issue but I'm actually more concerned about the site's visitors and reputation.

Comment: And therein lies my hesitation in this particular case. It includes a bundled browser toolbar which based on some googling does things like prevent you from changing your homepage and redirecting you to their search page, which as far as I'm concerned is malware but others may not see it that way.

Comment: @Nanhydrin  Hijacking your computer against the owners wishes is malware, even if mild.  Malware is just software that is maleficent: "causing or capable of producing evil or mischief; harmful or baleful."

Comment: The approach in this answer seems like the best plan to me. Just as a note, though, someone reading the answer who still wanted to try the software despite the warning could just look at the edit history to grab the link. No search is even required.

Comment: @reirab Good point, amended the answer.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Unlocker's site](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), Unlocker is not malware:

> — My antivirus complains about Unlocker, is there any malware?
>   — No, Unlocker will always be 100% safe

However, during install it offers to install a (presumably malicious) toolbar

> Promotional feature: Fully optional Delta toolbar.

This appears in the [changelog](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/#changes), and in bold text to make it more noticeable.

Of course, now it's up to you whether you should believe this or not. I can confirm unchecking the checbox didn't install the toolbar, and I didn't notice any suspicious behavior of Unlocker.

Comment: I'm now curious how many pieces of malware claim on their own site to be malware. :) The information in this answer is good to know, but, IMO, it's still best for us not to link to software whose installer offers to install malware, especially if option is checked by default.

Comment: Chrome warns me that http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ contains unsafe programs.

Comment: [VirusTotal analysis](https://virustotal.com/ca/file/b3284358029388637e642077f99e81e81144d8dab2f2623e263dbb5b625be746/analysis/). Most major antivirus seem to consider it safe, but there are 6 out of 56 detections.

Comment: @reirab Especially considering that about 99% of people who install software don't *read **anything*** when installing! This is why people have a thousand toolbars installed, why they have adware, etc.

Answer (score 4):

My opinion: If it's a link only answer, flag it as "Not an answer", and it will get deleted pretty quickly. However, if it's a good, useful answer, you could add a comment for the poster of the answer, telling them that the the software has changed and is now malicious. If the poster sees your comment, they can edit the answer and remove the link, or link to an older, non-malicious version of the software.

If the poster doesn't respond within a reasonable amount of time, yes, I think you should edit the answer and remove the link. Since you say that "*It includes the link as an alternative tactic at the end*", this should be fine, since the link is only a minor part of the answer. You should add a note in the edit summary noting what you did and why.

Personally, I think leaving a comment is a nice way to handle this, since it allows the poster of the answer to edit their answer as *they* see fit, and, if you forget to follow up on your comment later, with an edit, the comment serves as a "warning sign" for people looking at the answer.

Comment: I like to check the user's profile to see when they last were seen. When they are long gone, you might as well just change it immediately.

Comment: While I'm generally fine with this strategy, I'm not sure we need that much patience in the face of removing links to potentially dangerous downloads. If the link turns out to be harmless, the edit can easily be reverted later but if it doesn't and the link stays for any longer than necessary, people might be tricked into hurting themselves. It might also have legal consequences for SO.